# How to write "and" directive in sass

Tags: sass

I found good [mixin](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/05/offsets-sass-mixin/) written in "SCSS".

```
@mixin absolute($args) {
    $offsets: top right bottom left;
    @each $o in $offsets {
        $i: index($args, $o);

        @if $i 
        and $i + 1 <= length($args) 
        and type-of( nth($args, $i + 1) ) == number {
            #{$o}: nth($args, $i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

and, I convert this in "sass".

```
=absolute($args)
$offsets: top right bottom left
@each $o in $offsets
    $i: index($args, $o)
    @if $i 
    and $i + 1 <= length($args) 
    and type-of( nth($args, $i + 1) ) == number
        #{$o}: nth($args, $i + 1)
```

but, It has error...

```
Invalid CSS after "and ": expected selector, was "$i + 1 <= lengt..."
```

How should I write "and" directive in "sass"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works. All I did was put the `and`s in the same line

```
=absolute($args)
$offsets: top right bottom left
@each $o in $offsets
    $i: index($args, $o)
    @if $i and $i + 1 <= length($args) and type-of( nth($args, $i + 1) ) == number
        #{$o}: nth($args, $i + 1)
```